# Plural form of "someone"'?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns

> ***someone***
>
> Used for referring to a person when you do not know or do not say who the person is.

So in the sentence:

> I will need someone from different continents who can help me to spread this application and you are the first person that I approach.

Should the pronoun *someone* be plural and does it even have a plural form?

Or.. Should I just use the word *people* to replace the pronoun?

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56625/11762

Comment: "... the first person [that] *I have approached*."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone, and indeed any indefinite pronoun that ends in "one" is always singular. The word people is a good choice; however, the second part of your compound sentence sounds as if you are talking to only one person. You may want to restructure the sentence to reflect this.

Answer (score 12):

The plural you want for this case is "some people".

Comment: ... or just "people", thus "I will need people from different continents who, etc."

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally we see **someones**
From the OED:

> J. Curtis (1936).  There's someone on that roof all right. Two someones.

.

> J. Masefield (1927).  He had no sooner wished, than invisible someones came silently, blocked up the approach to Otter's lair,...

Answer (score 0):

Someones sounds so awkward, even hillbillyish, if you will.  But, it can be useful in dialogue, for effect.   Some people is Standard North American English, of course, for the plural form of somebody.