# Is the statement grammatically correct or not: "How can I get to watch a movie for free?"

Tags: grammar

I am having a sort of confusion, whether which of the following statements is/are correct:

"How can I get to watch  a movie for free?"

Or

"How do I get to watch  a movie for free?"

Comment: They are both in common use. Can I means now. Do I means I am curious about the method to use soon or not so soon. I you asked at a library, 'Can I' means immediate permission. 'Do I' means what is the procedure in general terms. In response to 'Do I,' a librarian may ask if you want to see a movie right now.

Comment: This is really an [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) question. @Atul - in most contexts, both your examples (and *How **could** I...?, How **will** I...?, etc.)* are equivalent. But in some "rhetorical question" contexts (where the speaker asks the question, then proceeds to answer it himself for the edification of others), your second version more strongly implies that the speaker *does already* watch movies for free (where the first version is more suitable if he hasn't yet started doing what he's about to explore and explain).

Answer (score -1):

The differences are very slight and often used interchangeably. "How do I" is asking for instruction with confidence. "How can I" is more uncertain, as if maybe you cannot do it.

So, "how do I get to watch a movie for free" sounds like you know it can be done and simply want to know how to do it. "How can I watch a movie for free" sounds like you are asking for instruction and if it is possible.

If you want to know more, try this older post:
[Is it better to say "How do I..." or "How can I..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30829/is-it-better-to-say-how-do-i-or-how-can-i)

Comment: Hello, Shaggy. You've done well to identify the duplicate, but please close-vote rather than repeat an answer.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to close or flag. Thanks though! :)

Comment: You don't need reputation not to repeat an answer.

Comment: Nothing wrong with helping someone and it also helped someone else mark it as a dup. Win win in my book. :)